# Oracle SQL using Like for a wildcard

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause, sql-like

I know you can use LIKE for a select statement to search for a string and then use wildcards to match that string.. ex:

`Select * from table where first_name LIKE '%r%';`

Would return names such as robert, roland, craig, etc.

I'm curious how you would search for an actual wildcard in the string such as the %:

`Select * from table where values LIKE '%  %  %';`

(the middle % being what you would be looking for) (obviously this is not the correct way to do it which is why I'm asking).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

Comment: Seems to work great, thanks, didn't know about the escape char function of like :)

Answer (score -3):

Just LIKE '%%' will be even easier.

Comment: No, because this expression will watch anything

Comment: Thought about voting to delete this answer, but actually it serves as a useful tip to Seekers on what not to do :)